In Rocky 9 Cinnamon, how can I change the 'Turn off the screen when inactive for' setting via ansible?
I have an ansible-built system which needs to stay online for 2 hours before the screen locks. However, whatever I try I can't seem to modify the System Settings - Power Options - "Turn off the screen when inactive for" dropdown without physically clicking on the dropdown and changing it, which defeats the purpose of having an ansible system at all.
By running:
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session idle-delay 7200

I can successfully modify the inbuilt screensaver utility to turn on the screensaver after 7200 seconds (2 hours). However, long before that point, the default (15 minutes) setting for 'Turn off the screen when inactive for' is reached and the screen turns off.
I have used the command:
xset dpms 40 40 40 

To make the screen go black after 40 seconds, but when I set it for longer than the dropdown menu, the dropdown takes precedent and the screen goes black after the default 15 minutes.
None of the following have worked:
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session idle-delay 7200
dconf write /org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/power/turn-off-screen-on-idle 7200

And when looking, neither /etc/xdg/cinnamon-settings-daemon/power.conf nor ~/.config/cinnamon-settings-daemon/power.conf exist to modify.

I have figured it out.
To find out what system variable changes when you toggle any settings in the GUI menu, all you need to do is open a terminal window and run:
dconf watch /
Then change the setting and see what lines show up when you do.
In the end, I added to my ansible script to both run the setting change manually and append it to bashrc so that every time the user logs in the setting is changed back to 2 hours, as I want.

name: desktop.yml - Add to ~/.bashrc
blockinfile:
state: present
insertafter: EOF
dest: /home/{{item.0.name}}/.bashrc
block: |
dconf write /org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-display-ac 7200
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/session/idle-delay 7200
marker: "# {mark}"  # Adds a marker to identify this block
with_nested:

"{{ users }}"


name: Set dconf value for display off
become: true
become_user: "{{ item.name }}"
command: dbus-launch dconf write /org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-display-ac 7200
with_items:

"{{ users }}"


name: Set dconf value for idle delay (Screensaver)
become: true
become_user: "{{ item.name }}"
command: dbus-launch dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/session/idle-delay 7200
with_items:

"{{ users }}"



